# I need to save all the job overviews int an array list, sorry if there is an obvious answer I am very new to java and android

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

**Database**
[image: this is a image of the database I am referring to]

I have tried using `orderByChild` and nested for loops, but i am not sure how which method to use or how to use it. The purpose is to display cards of various strings in JOBOVERVIEW. Do you fellow stackoverflowrians have an answer, I have been stuck for a while and dont know where to proceed form here.

cheers and please dont hate.

```
package com.example.sherwin.todo;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class JobList extends Fragment {

    public JobList() {
    }
    public static JobList newInstance() {
        JobList fragment = new JobList();

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_job_list, container, false);
        final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.job_list_recycler_view);

        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
        final ArrayList<JobClass> joblistclass  = new ArrayList<>();

        final DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("USERS/04950F4AE53F80/JOBS");



        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot data:dataSnapshot.getChildren()
                            ) {
                        if (data.getChildren().equals("JOBOVERVIEW")){
                            JobClass jblst = data.getValue(JobClass.class);
                            joblistclass.add(jblst);
                        }
                    }

                final JobListRecyclerAdapter adapterb = new JobListRecyclerAdapter(joblistclass);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterb);

            }



            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w("TAG:", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate what are you trying to achieve ? do you want to store the job overviews ? or display ?

Comment: I am trying to display cards in recycleview with the info of the children under OVERVIEW{jobDate, jobDeet,..jobDate}ect     there will be several cards one for every child under JOBS{12,123,523...} . it shld display 4 cards in total

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference jobsRef = rootRef
        .child("USERS")
        .child("04950F4AE53F80")
        .child("JOBS");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String jobDate = ds.child("JOBOVERVIEW").child("jobDate").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", jobDate);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
jobsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

And the output will be:

```
29/09
2/2
//and so on
```